# Laravel return image preview from base64

Tags: image, laravel, base64

I have base64 image and I want to return the image preview not the base64 code.

I tried

```
return response(base64_decode($results->getBase64Image()), 200, ['Content-Type' => 'image/png']);
```

but it returns a weird output.
[image: Result]

Comment: what do you mean by return?? where do you want to returen??

Comment: I tried but same result @linktoahref

Comment: I want to return the image preview @Sohel0415

Comment: first save the file, then show it from disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an answer.
[imagecreatefromjpeg() php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577903/imagecreatefromjpeg-php/5578164#5578164)

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($results->getBase64Image()));
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        return imagejpeg($image);
```

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.8 and above...

Just straightaway put the string into `response()`...
and add `header('Content-Type', 'image/png')`

For example:

```
$raw_image_string = base64_decode($base64_img_string);

return response($raw_image_string)->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this..  for base 64 images ))))

```
function store()
{
    $data = $this->request->img;
    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);

    $directory_bucekts = implode('/',str_split(strtolower(str_random(2))));

    Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('images/shopdata/'.$directory_bucekts, true, true);

//        mkdir(storage_path('app/public/images/shopdata/'.$directory_bucekts), 755, true);

    $data         = base64_decode($data);

    $fileName     = time().rand(100,1000).'.jpg';
    $path         = storage_path('app/public/images/shopdata/'.$directory_bucekts);

    file_put_contents($path .'/'. $fileName, $data);

    return response()->make(['path' =>  '/storage/images/shopdata/' . $directory_bucekts. '/' .$fileName]);

}
```

Comment: base from your example, is it possible not to store the image?

Comment: you must store image and then get image in preview

Comment: Ohh.. I see.. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

You may return the `base64` code to a view and in the view, render the image using `<img>` tag

```
$base64code = $results->getBase64Image();
return view('preview', compact('base64code'));
```

Blade File:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ $base64code }}" alt="Image Preview" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i want to render the image as return not from view/blade.

Comment: Do you meant let the end user download the Image Preview?

Comment: Just a preview of the image, like if you input the base64 to the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```php
class ImagesController extends Controller{

  public function store(Request $request, YourImageModel $imageModel){
    
    $image = base64_decode($imageModel->base64Content);
    $path = Storage::putFile('images', $image);
    
    return response()->file($path);

  }

}
```

You can read the doc for [Request File uploading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#files), [File Uploading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads) and [File Responses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#file-responses), they all are under Laravel's documentation.

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
        $data = base64_decode($results->getBase64Image());
        $image_name= time().'_test_.png';
        $path = public_path() .'/'. $image_name;

        file_put_contents($path, $data);

        //serve the image
       return  response()->file($path);
```

See [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-responses).

Comment: Thank you, but it only saves the image to the public folder, is there a way to create preview of the image?