# How to extract base64 image from text in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How to extract base64 image from text? I tried to use simple html dom library but couldn't extract it from text. I need to extract each base64 and convert it to an image then save it to public folder.

Code:

```
  $post = \App\Post::find(45);
    $dom = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html( $post->content );
    foreach ($dom->find('data:image') as $element) {
        dd($element);
    }
```

```
<p style="text-align:right"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to ma</p>

<p style="text-align:right">data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/2wCEAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB .... == </p>
```

Comment: imo, no need for simple html dom, you can use `DOMDocument`, in PHP already built-in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel return image preview from base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496474/laravel-return-image-preview-from-base64)

Comment: @Ballard it needs to be a two part solution, the first is to extract the base64 image in the paragraph tag first, iterate all the results and use the conversion which your answer contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question is :

1. Install paquettg/php-html-parser package.
2. Install intervention/image.
3. use the following code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

$posts = Post::where('content_edited',0)->orderBy('id','asc')->take(100)->get();

foreach ($posts as $post)
{
    $dom = new Dom;
    $dom->loadStr($post->content);
    $imgs = $dom->find('img');

    if ($imgs->count() > 0 )
    {

        $i =0 ;
        foreach ($imgs as $img)
        {

            $image_src = $img->src;
            $result = Str::contains($image_src, 'data:image');
            if ($result)
            {
                preg_match("/data:image\/(.*?);/", $image_src, $image_extension);
                $image_src = preg_replace('/data:image\/(.*?);base64,/', '', $image_src); // remove the type part
                $image_src = str_replace(' ', '_', $image_src);
                $imageName = 'image_' .$i.Factory::create()->uuid . '.' . $image_extension[1];
                Image::make(base64_decode($image_src))->save(public_path('/photos/inline/') . $imageName);
                $tag = $img->getTag();
                $tag->setAttribute('src','/photos/inline/'.$imageName);
                $post->content_edited = 1;

            }
            $i++;
        }
        $post->content_edited = 1;
        $post->content = $dom;
        $post->save();
    }else{

        $post->content_edited = 1;
        $post->save();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a duplicate, depending on if you want to save the image to your server first or not, please see answer by Kerwin or linktoahref

[Laravel return image preview from base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496474/laravel-return-image-preview-from-base64)

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($results->getBase64Image()));
header('Content-type: image/png');
return imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: I don't have problem with converting the image or saving it. All I want is to know how I can extract base64 images from text in post content which is between p tags .

Comment: I tried this code but not working the way I want because i get this error : member function getBase64Image() on string